# How to Redirect Laravel application to Separate HTML Landing Page

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I Have Ultimate SMS Application in Laravel at the below link
`http://clickysms.com/`
In this laravel application, there is no landing page, it is directly open the client login page. 
I have design Separate Landing Page(including 20 HTML pages) for this website in HTML with folder name **home** and Upload in my Webhostingfile manager in the dictionary `clickysms.com/home`. 
**What is Want:** When anyone open main domain `clickysms.com` then it should be redirected to `clickysms/home` for first time. 
how to do it? 
remember that my application in Laravel and landing page (Have 20 HTML pages) design in HTML and in a folder name Home.